# How to cut string after a specific line number?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

I have a **string** - project description ( as part of an object ) coming from a user form submission that is shown on a page of a report. If the **line numbers** exceed 24 I want to show **the rest of the string** on a **new page**. My initial idea was to cut it based on **characters** but this can't be done precisely as if line breaks are made when submitting the form, the characters can't be calculated as we don´t know if the line break was made in the middle of a line or the end or wherever. I don't know what could be the solution?

How can I cut a string based on number of lines?

This is what I have done so far:

```
function countLines (el) {
    let projectDetails = $rootScope.report.description;
    var el = document.getElementById(el);
    var divHeight = el.offsetHeight
    var lines = divHeight / 17;
    //console.log("Lines counted: " + lines);
    if(lines > 24) {
        $scope.secondDescriptionPage = true;
        $scope.projectDetailsTextFirstPart = // this should be calculated
        //$scope.projectDetailsTextSecondPart =  // this should be calculated )
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to count a line wrap as a new line or just new line characters?

Comment: yeah both line wraps and new lines, as you can see I count them visually based on line-height ( 17 stands for that )

Comment: So after some thinking I am certain what you want to do is hardly possible. I've only come up with one solution that would work in every case, but it is too horrible and another one that only works with mono space fonts . You are probably out of luck here, maybe try a different approach to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

With the `-webkit-line-clamp` CSS property you can cut text by a certain number of lines. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp) for details. It will not work in IE11 however.